# How do I use pandas to add a calculated column in a pivot table?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, calculated-columns

I'm using pandas 0.16.0 & numpy 1.9.2
I did the following to add a calculated field (column) in the pivot table

Set up dataframe as follows,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'] * 6, 'B' : ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 8, 'C' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'] * 4, 'D' : np.random.randn(24), 'E' : np.random.randn(24), 'F' : [datetime.datetime(2013, i, 1) for i in range(1, 13)] + [datetime.datetime(2013, i, 15) for i in range(1, 13)]})
```

Pivoted the data frame as follows,

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(values=['D'],index=['A'],columns=['C'],aggfunc=np.sum,margins=False)
```

Tried adding a calculated field as follows, but I get an error (see below),

```
df1['D2'] = df1['D'] * 2
```

Error,

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a **Hierarchical Index** (i.e. MultiIndex) as columns in your 'pivot table' dataframe.
If you print out reslults of `df1['D'] * 2` you will notice that you get two columns:

```
C        bar     foo
A                   
one   -3.163 -10.478
three -2.988   1.418
two   -2.218   3.405
```

So to put it back to `df1` you need to provide two columns to assign it to:

```
df1[[('D2','bar'), ('D2','foo')]] = df1['D'] * 2
```

Which yields:

```
           D            D2        
C        bar    foo    bar     foo
A                                 
one   -1.581 -5.239 -3.163 -10.478
three -1.494  0.709 -2.988   1.418
two   -1.109  1.703 -2.218   3.405
```

A more generalized approach:

```
new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(('D2', df1.D.columns))
df1[new_cols] = df1.D * 2
```

You can find more info on how to deal with MultiIndex in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Also, what if I don't know the distinct column values (foo, bar); how do I extend this to be generic?

Comment: Added generalized approach to the answer.